# Angular child route redirecting to parent route not loading parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

UPDATE:
I am just going to edit component code, which I really did not want to do but in being conscientious of timelines I am removing the value from the URL using the location.go() method

I have an angular 8 application that I am working on. I am trying to make a child route redirect to its parent route when the route is incomplete or malformed. When using redirectTo, the application will correctly update the url but it appears that the component is not being loaded again.

Below is a sample of my router code.

```
{
    path: 'route1',       
    component: RouteComponent,
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id/:id2',
            component: RouteComponentDetails,                
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            redirectTo: '/route1',
        },
    ],        
}
```

If I have the route set like this, the route will correctly reload but it leaves the :id param in the URL which I do not want. I've also tried setting path to ** which will corrrectly change the route, it will just not reload the component when using redirectTo.

```
{
    path: 'route1',       
    component: RouteComponent,
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id/:id2',
            component: RouteComponentDetails,                
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: RouteComponent,
        },
    ],        
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Instead of setting child route you could use `router.navigate(['route1'])` inside component when route is `:id`

Comment: preferably this can be handled via the route config rather than editing component code. if push comes to shove, that will be my next step but I am very much trying to avoid this

Comment: Replace this `redirectTo: '/route1',` with `redirectTo: 'route1',` remove slash give it try.

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.

Comment: what about to listen the params changes from the child component? you can listen params changes and when you will get both params you can do the same instead of reload the component.